# Help Finding Resources for a Career Mentor (WP/Web Development)

Tags: job-search, career-development, career-switch

I am a junior-level WordPress/web developer in Northeast Massachusetts who is in some desperate need of some career guidance and mentorship.

Where can I find a resource to help me find a knowledgeable and established individual who could help answer some questions for me and help with planning/strategy for my path into this field?

Or in other words:

Where can I find a mentor?

I am starting to go to WP Meetups in the hopes of meeting some people who may be able to help but other than that I am not sure where to look for help.

I am a very hard worker and determined to find my way into this field, and I would offer any of my various services/skills as trade.

Any help, ideas or resources will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you~

Comment: If we are talking about online places, wordpress.stackexchange.com is a good place. Just answer a few of the simpler questions and also start to be a `hangaround` in the chat and to follow the conversations there.

Comment: Northeast Massachusetts? Like Cape Ann?

Comment: I'm Amesbury/Newburyport area, close to Cape Ann...

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you find your mentor at your workplace, as both parties will have a mutually beneficial relationship. He/She, i.e., your mentor, takes away from his time to guide you in the right direction and in return, your actions will make the workplace better for him and everyone else.

Outside the workplace, if you can find a decent mentor, it will be the out of the goodness of your mentor's heart. And you will not be the only on, vying for this spot. So, your chances of having this mentor/student relationship out of your workplace is pretty slim. But you took the right step by joining meetups. After a few meetings, you will figure out the regulars and and try striking up a chat with them, in a friendly way. If they are willing to get into this mentorship state, it should come naturally, not like you blurting out "I Need a mentor". Also, consider participating in online forums in your field. Not any forum but reputable ones. There are plenty of people, giving good advice online. You just need to be patient and learn to differentiate between an expert and a BS artist.

Comment: I am looking for a mentor in order to get an entry level job/paid internship, so unfortunately the workplace is not an option for me.   Thanks for the advice with Meetups, that is what I planned to do and I will hope that I can meet some people there.  I am not sure I would know which forums are reputable in web dev or WP, so any names would be appreciated. Thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find a mentor?

If you went to college - start there. Many schools can connect you with graduates who can help out.

Meetups could be helpful. Conferences are great networking places too - and folks in your network might become a mentor over time.

Comment: Unfortunately I have exhausted the limited resources available at the CC that I graduated from, but this is one of the first places where I looked to try and figure things out.....Yes I am hoping that getting familiar with the crowd at Meetups will be an opportunity to eventually find someone who may be willing to give me some career advice. Thanks Joe

Answer (score -1):

Google mentoring groups, I'm familiar with S.C.O.R.E. but I am sure there are other ones out there.